# How do you use count plot and line plot with the same Y axis in Seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use a countplot and a lineplot with the same Y axis. It is working, but the plot I got has an issue on the X axis. The X axis (especially, for the secondary Y-axis) does not start where I want it to start (at point 1).

I tried other ways, but nothing is working.

```
sns.set(style='dark')
fig, ax1=plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))

plt.title("Plot of farmers' take home and count by cycle", fontsize=13)
ax2=ax1.twinx()

sns.countplot(ax=ax1, x=data["Flock_number"], palette="ch:.25", data=data)
sns.lineplot(ax=ax2, x=data["Flock_number"], y=data["Take_home"], color='r',ci='sd')


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I would like to see both "Count" and ("Take_home") to start at 1 on X axis.